Keyframes in the dope sheet are uneditable, is this a bug?
I am very new to blender and im unsure if this is a bug or not
The selected frames on the dope sheet are permanently seletced and i can't move and edit them in anyway
Whenever i move the keyframes in the layout timeline it doesn't actually change the animation until the original 35 frames are over, and then it plays the animation again but only for some parts
im clueless

hello, could you please share your file with the animated object only? Maybe you have locked the bones?

I did manage to find the issue and fix it, your comment was very helpful tysm!

oh ok great!!!!
